# ListView and ArrayAdapter configuration, android app

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity, android-arrayadapter

AFter Many hours of working on getting ListView to work with my DB, I have finally managed to get it to compile.  Now that I know things are communicating properly (i.e. the Database info to a listview) I was wondering if someone could suggest ways of making it more useful.  I noticed when I run the app, the listview items appear to be clickable, but lead nowhere.  how can I add to my code that so when an item is clicked, it opens up a new activity with all of the items information?

```
private void showEvents() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = post.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("SELECT "+TITLE+", "+LINK+", "+POST+", "+DATE+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" "+"ORDER BY "+DATE+" DESC;",null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    //TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    //ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    ListView lv1 = new ListView(this);
    lv1.setId(2000);


    // Stuff them all into a big string
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
    ArrayList<String> codes = new ArrayList<String>();
     while(cursor.moveToNext()){
         String title = cursor.getString(0);
         //builder.append("Title:  ").append(title).append("\n");

         String link = cursor.getString(1);
         //builder.append("Link:  ").append(link).append("\n");

         String post = cursor.getString(2);
         //builder.append("Post:  ").append(post).append("\n");

         String date = cursor.getString(3);
         //builder.append("Date:  ").append(date).append("\n");
         codes.add(title);

     }
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, codes);
     lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
     this.setContentView(lv1);

     //tv.setText(builder);
     //this.setContentView(tv);
 }
```

For example, when I add codes.add(title), I want to click that item and view the rest of that contents fields (such as the link, description, date).  Most tutorials out there don't deal with this arrayadaper setup so its hard to know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a click listener to your list view and then have a way to figure out what was clicked and start the new activity.  Something like this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
        String textOfSelectedItem  =((TextView) view).getText().toString();     
         //Create our intent             
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);                              
        i.putExtra("Place", textOfSelectedItem);
        startActivity(i);
      }
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm away from my computer currently, but if this proves to be the solution I'll make sure and accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is confusing, you should write a custom adapter which extends CursorAdapter.

You may want to check out the [NotePad](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html) sample app on the android dev website.